How to build a working Nix package from an ASP.NET project?
I am able to build the project using buildDotnetModule and then install it by adding to environment.systemPackages. But when run from the terminal the website does not work properly:
Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://my.app/css/site.css - 404 0

This seems to be because MyApp does not know where to find wwwroot. I am not even sure it gets copied to the derivation.

@DavidGrayson ASP.NET Core includes a web server called Kestrel, so it doesn't necessarily need anything in front of it. In addition to all the ASP.NET Core specific frameworks, it can serve static assets.

Turns out ASP.NET allows you to override wwwroot location by setting environment variable WEBROOT.
When you are building a NixOS service, you can set it using
WEBROOT = "${myapp}/lib/myapp/wwwroot";

where myapp is your package/derivation.
I've added this info with more details and a complete example to https://wiki.nixos.org/wiki/DotNET
